# Calculate 6*9 in different bases

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity

Output the following result (which is a result of calculating 6 * 9 in bases from 2 to 36). Make sure letters are uppercase, and the multiplication itself is outputed on every line.

```
6 * 9 = 110110
6 * 9 = 2000
6 * 9 = 312
6 * 9 = 204
6 * 9 = 130
6 * 9 = 105
6 * 9 = 66
6 * 9 = 60
6 * 9 = 54
6 * 9 = 4A
6 * 9 = 46
6 * 9 = 42
6 * 9 = 3C
6 * 9 = 39
6 * 9 = 36
6 * 9 = 33
6 * 9 = 30
6 * 9 = 2G
6 * 9 = 2E
6 * 9 = 2C
6 * 9 = 2A
6 * 9 = 28
6 * 9 = 26
6 * 9 = 24
6 * 9 = 22
6 * 9 = 20
6 * 9 = 1Q
6 * 9 = 1P
6 * 9 = 1O
6 * 9 = 1N
6 * 9 = 1M
6 * 9 = 1L
6 * 9 = 1K
6 * 9 = 1J
6 * 9 = 1I
```

Shortest code wins.

Comment: It's the result from bases 2 to 36, not 10 to 36.

Comment: @Howard: Fixed. I was considering changing 2 to 10, but forgot about this edit while fixing something else in the result, so I accidentally left it the wrong way.

Comment: The challenge would be more interesting if you weren't allowed to use to use library functions for base conversion.

Comment: `Calculate 6*9 in different bases` I wonder why the statement is worded thus, why `6*9` and not simply `54`? Perhaps the originally intended meaning was that `6` and `9` should be interpreted not always as decimal but in different bases? That would make the statement more logical, and the problem more interesting (but then we should start from base 10 to 36)

Comment: @leonbloy: `6` and `9` are single-digit numbers. They mean the same in every base in which those digits are valid.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: Correct, but `6 * 9 = 110110` doesn't make a lot of sense...

Comment: This is a reference to the Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy series by Douglas Adams.  In the series, the Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, The Universe, and Everything is "42".  Later, its revealed that the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything is "What do you get when you multiply six by nine?", which works out in base-13. Note: Douglas Adams said this was unintentional; ["I don't write jokes in base-13"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life.2C_the_Universe.2C_and_Everything_.2842.29).

Comment: @leonbloy - "I wonder why the statement is worded thus," it's worded that way because of Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy series.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life.2C_the_Universe.2C_and_Everything_.2842.29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>21</s> 20 bytes

```
36G54N>B"6 * 9 = ÿ",
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f2Mzd1MTPzknJTEFLwVLBVuHwfiWd//8B)

Comment: I assume it's non-competing just because the language is newer than a challenge? Marking as accepted, as rules as of now allow this.

Comment: @xfix pretty much haha

Answer (score 7):

#### GolfScript, 39 characters

```
35,{2+'6 * 9 = '54@base{.9>7*+48+}%n+}/
```

Result can be seen [here](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=MzUsezIrJzYgKiA5ID0gJzU0QGJhc2V7Ljk%2BNyorNDgrfSVuK30v&run=true).

Answer (score 7):

### Octave, 49

`for i=2:36printf("6 * 9 = %s\n",dec2base(54,i))end`

Answer (score 6):

## Javascript, <s>57</s> 55 bytes

```
for(i=2;++i<37;)console.log('6 * 9 = '+54..toString(i))
```

Could be shortened to 49 with `alert`, but I don't want to submit anyone to that...

Comment: Output should be uppercase, and `(54)` can be replaced with `54.` (to write `54..toString`).

Comment: `for(i=1;++i<37;)` also saves a character.

Comment: Can you ignore the 37? It will result in an error and stop

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby (47)

```
2.upto(36){|t|puts"9 * 6 = "+54.to_s(t).upcase}
```

Well, I know that GolfScript solution is better, but hey, at least this is not esoteric...

Comment: `2.step{|t|puts"9 * 6 = "+54.to_s(t).upcase}` saves a few bytes. It exits with an error, but [that's ok :D](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4781/58569).

Answer (score 4):

### Python, 89

```
B=lambda x:x*'.'and B(x/b)+chr(x%b+7*(x%b>9)+48)
b=2
while b<37:print'6 * 9 =',B(54);b+=1
```

Comment: Brilliant. Quite noticeable that I'm a total Python noob in comparison :)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Thanks... I've got loads more to learn.

Comment: You can shave off one character by using a while loop instead: `b=2` <linebreak> `while b<37:print'6 * 9 =',B(54);b+=1` (assuming single character for a *nix linebreak)

Comment: @Bob Whenever I try a while loop, it's too expensive.  Then, I forget to try the next time.  ;)  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**Python 2.7 (<s>124</s> 114)**

EDIT: Cut some fluff thanks to @boothby's comment below

I think Python is doing ok considering it has no built-in (that I know of) to do the base conversion so it has to be done in code;

```
for b in range(2,37):print'6 * 9 = '+''.join(chr((54/b**y%b>9)*7+48+54/b**y%b)for y in range(4,-1,-1)).lstrip('0')
```

Comment: I have to remind myself of this continually: `print'\n'.join(...for x in y)` is rather longer than `for x in y:print...`.

Comment: @boothby Thanks, updated with your suggestion :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 36 bytes

```
say '6 * 9 = ',54.base($_) for 2..36
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica 40

Not in contention (lower case letters used):

```
Print["6*9 = ",54~BaseForm~#]&/@2~Range~36
```

[image: base output]

Answer (score 1):

## J - <del>78</del> 70

```
'6 * 9 = ',"1>;/(a.#~48 10 7 26 165#0 1 0 1 0){~<&.>(2+i.35)#.inv&.>54
```

## Haskell - 137

```
let s=['0'..'9']++['A'..'Z'];t _(0,r)=[s!!r];t b(q,r)=(t b$b q)++[s!!r]in mapM_(putStrLn.("6 * 9 = "++).(\b->t b$b 54).flip divMod)[2..36]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Perl**

Had to use the Math::BaseCnv module

35 chars without the `use` statement:

```
map{say"6 * 9 = ",cnv(54,$_)}2..36
```

54 chars with the `use` statement:

```
use Math::BaseCnv;
map{say"6 * 9 = ",cnv(54,$_)}2..36
```

Not sure how you'd score this, so both are included.

The map BLOCK LIST structure was used.  List is the range 2 to 36, that was requested.  The meat is in the `cnv($NUMBER, $BASE)` function, and the map is an implied loop.

Comment: Count the `use` statement.  The first one doesn't work in my perl.

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 60 bytes

```julia
for b=2:36;@printf("6 * 9 = %s\n",uppercase(base(b,54)));end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@/8/Lb9IIcnWyMrYzNqhoCgzryRNQ8lMQUvBUsFWQbU4Jk9Jp7SgILUoObE4VSMJTOiYmmhqalqn5qX8/w8A)

Pretty painless, apart from remembering to use the macro @printf versus printf.

Import Base; not needed ...

Comment: `for b=2:36;println("6 * 9 = $(uppercase(base(b,54)))");end` is also good...

Answer (score 1):

### C (<strike>166</strike> 151)

Got rid of some unnecessary characters and changed some declarations. Assumes that you are running the program with no arguments.

```
p[7],i,l,v,r;main(b){for(r=2;r<37;r++){b++;printf("6 * 9 = ");v=54;while(v>0)l=v%b,p[i++]=l>9?l+55:l+48,v/=b;while(i^0)printf("%c",p[--i]);puts("");}}
```

Answer (score 1):

**CoffeeScript 71**

```
alert ("6 * 9 = "+59.toString(x).toUpperCase()for x in[2..36]).join "\n"
```

[Link](http://tinyurl.com/oeq8xby)

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure, 75

`(for[i(range 2 37)](println"6 * 9 ="(.toUpperCase(Integer/toString 54 i))))`

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 83 bytes

```
import numpy;print('\n'.join('6 * 9 = '+numpy.base_repr(54,i)for i in range(2,37)))
```

Comment: You can use `'\n'.join('6 * 9 = '+numpy.base_repr(54,i)for i in range(2,37))` instead of `*['6 * 9 = '+numpy.base_repr(54,i)for i in range(2,37)],sep='\n'` to save a byte.

Comment: You should probably specify "Python 3 with Numpy" as it's not a standard library

Comment: @FlipTack Without numpy I can get it down to 143 if I have to hardcode `'0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'`, or down to 130 if I'm allowed to import `string.printable` (but that results in lowercase instead of uppercase): [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HctBCsIwEEDRfU8xFKSJlrZYRRFyEnWRwaSmJJMwzcbTx@jy83npk9@R5mviUizHAFtmRwu4kCLnfWOV1wFfGqjHWzu1zgIpNRm/GbCCxhF7lIP/qSTql4dUfdbozZ12@Gz@KboHdcMaHQkrzqdKbGRAcASsaTHi2M8XKWUpXw "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online"). Do you think that's worth making an answer?

Answer (score 1):

## Dart, 75 bytes

```
for(int x=2;x<37;x++)print("6 * 9 = ${54.toRadixString(x).toUpperCase()}");
```

Dart is a bit verbose when it comes to the stdlib, but hey... at least you can read it :P

Answer (score 0):

### Scala, 71

```
2 to 36 map(i=>println("6 * 9 = "+Integer.toString(54,i).toUpperCase))
```

Answer (score 0):

Common Lisp: 56 characters

```
(do((b 2(1+ b)))((> b 36))(format t"6 * 9 = ~vr~%"b 54))
```

Answer (score 0):

### Sage, 48:

Shame Sage prints in lowercase... I'd only be one over Howard.  Or, I guess, wrong and tied with David Carraher.

```
for i in[2..36]:print'6 * 9 =',54.str(i).upper()
```

Answer (score 0):

### Forth, 54

```
: f 54 37 2 do ." 6 * 9 = " dup i base ! . cr loop ; f
```

Answer (score 0):

## [///](//esolangs.org/wiki////), 133 bytes

```
/R/6 * 9 = //S/
R/R110110S2000S312S204S130S105S66S60S54S4AS46S42S3CS39S36S33S30S2GS2ES2CS2AS28S26S24S22S20S1QS1PS1OS1NS1MS1LS1KS1JS1I
```

[Try it online!](//slashes.tryitonline.net#code=L1IvNiAqIDkgPSAvL1MvClIvUjExMDExMFMyMDAwUzMxMlMyMDRTMTMwUzEwNVM2NlM2MFM1NFM0QVM0NlM0MlMzQ1MzOVMzNlMzM1MzMFMyR1MyRVMyQ1MyQVMyOFMyNlMyNFMyMlMyMFMxUVMxUFMxT1MxTlMxTVMxTFMxS1MxSlMxSQ)

Answer (score 0):

## SpecBAS - 48 bytes

```
1 FOR i=2 TO 36: ?"6 * 9 = ";BASE$(54,i): NEXT i
```

SpecBAS is actually quite competitive for a change :-)

Answer (score 0):

## [8th](http://8th-dev.com/), <s>65</s> 62 bytes

This is a complete program. Exit after execution

```
( "6 * 9 = " . #54 swap base drop >s s:uc . cr ) 2 36 loop bye
```

**Explanation**

```
( 
   "6 * 9 = " .   \ Print the first part of the formula
    #54 swap base \ Enter into the base provided by loop index and                
                  \ convert 54 (which is always expressed in base 10)
    drop          \ Get rid of previous base
    >s s:uc       \ Convert number into an upper case string
    . cr          \ Print result and newline
) 2 36 loop       \ Provide base from 2 to 36
bye               \ Quit
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-2) `rRMj`, 119 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 14.875 bytes

```
34ƛ⇧54R`6*9=`ṄðpJ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyJyUk1qPSIsIiIsIjM0xpvih6c1NFJgNio5PWDhuYTDsHBKIiwiIiwiIl0=)

Bitstring:

```
01001000111011011000001000111100010001001111010001100010011111010011011001011001000000010100011011001000011111011100011
```

so many flags

```
34ƛ⇧54R`6*9=`ṄðpJ­⁡​‎‏​⁢⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁣​‎‏​⁢⁠⁡‌­
# ‎⁡R flag casts numbers to ranges
# ‎⁡M flag starts implicit ranges at 0
# The r flag reverses the arguments which makes the base conversion easier
34ƛ                # ‎⁢map over the range 0-34
   ⇧               # ‎⁣add 2, giving a range 2-36
    54R            # ‎⁤Convert 54 to base B
       `6*9=`Ṅ     # ‎⁢⁡separate the multiplication by spaces
              ðpJ  # ‎⁢⁢add a space, and append the converted base 

# -j flag joins output on newlines
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 59 bytes

```julia
2:36 .|>b->println("6 * 9 = ",uppercase(string(54,base=b)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/38jK2ExBr8YuSdeuoCgzryQnT0PJTEFLwVLBVkFJp7SgILUoObE4VaO4BCibrmFqopME5NomaWpq/v8PAA)

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 46 bytes

```julia
@.println("6 * 9 = ",uppercase(base(2:36,54)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@//fQa@gKDOvJCdPQ8lMQUvBUsFWQUmntKAgtSg5sThVIwlEGFkZm@mYmmhqav7/DwA)